# Fail to build PyTorch at libtorch_cuda.so (using conda)

Tags: pytorch

I'm building PyTorch from source to get RTX3090 support (sm86) but it keeps error. The machine has Nvidia Driver 455+, Cuda 11.1 and CuDNN 8.1. I use conda and installed magma-cuda111-2.5.2. Anyone can help?

P/S: I'm thinking about the error caused by ld. the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is
`/usr/local/cuda/lib64` in conda (I set it as a tutorial when install CUDA).

```
FAILED: bin/roi_align_op_gpu_test 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -fopenmp -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Werror=return-type -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-psabi -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Werror=format -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-stringop-overflow -DHAVE_AVX_CPU_DEFINITION -DHAVE_AVX2_CPU_DEFINITION -O3 -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG -rdynamic caffe2/CMakeFiles/roi_align_op_gpu_test.dir/operators/roi_align_op_gpu_test.cc.o -o bin/roi_align_op_gpu_test  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib:  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so  lib/libgtest_main.a  -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch.so" -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cpu.so" -Wl,--as-needed  lib/libprotobuf.a  lib/libdnnl.a  -ldl  -Wl,--no-as-needed,"/home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so" -Wl,--as-needed  lib/libc10_cuda.so  lib/libc10.so  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnvToolsExt.so  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so  lib/libgtest.a  -pthread && :
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `zgemm_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `sgebak_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `zgehd2_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `zgemv_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `dlascl_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `slartg_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `dger_'
....
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `zpotrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `sgeqrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/hieupth/Downloads/pytorch/build/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined reference to `icamax_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Those errors have nothing to do with CUDA. They are missing BLAS/LAPACK functions